# How to create a regular expression which identifies two strings without an embedded character

Tags: regex, vba

I'm trying to identify a regex in VBA which will identify the occurrence of two strings within parentheses, with no intervening parentheses.

For example, search string A is `ccc` and search string B is `yyy`.

So, this target string:

`(aaa, xxx (ccc,ddd, yyy) abc)`

should return true because of the match on:

`(ccc, ddd, yyy)`

But this target string:

`(aaa, xxx (ccc, abc) yyy)`

should return false because it doesn't have a match on `(ccc, yyy)` due the intervening right paren.

I've tried using the "not" character, e.g.,

`\(.*ccc[^\(\)]*yyy*\)`

That is saying "give me the string with `ccc` and `yyy` as long as there is *not* 1 or more occurrences of of left paren or right paren in between the two.

However it keeps returning the entire string.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two questions

1. The pattern to match. I used `".*?(\(" & strIn1 & "[^\)]+" & strIn2 & "\))"`
2. Returning the portion the matches

The key part is
`"[^\)]+"`
ie there cannot be a right bracket *anywhere* before the second string

```
Function ValidateText(strIn1 As String, strIn2 As String, strTarget As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim bMatch As Boolean
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
s = ".*?\(.*(" & strIn1 & "[^\)]+" & strIn2 & ".*\))"
.Pattern = ".*?\(.*(" & strIn1 & "[^\)]+" & strIn2 & ").*\)"
bMatch = .TEst(strTarget)
If bMatch Then
ValidateText = "this portion matched " & vbNewLine & .Replace(strTarget, "$1") & vbNewLine & "for " & strIn1 & " " & strIn2
Else
ValidateText = "no match for " & vbNewLine & .Replace(strTarget, "$1") & vbNewLine & "for " & strIn1 & " " & strIn2
End If
End With
End Function

Sub Test1()
MsgBox ValidateText("ccc", "yyy", "(aaa, xxx (ccc,ddd, yyy) abc)")
MsgBox ValidateText("ccc", "yyy", "(aaa, xxx (ccc, abc) yyy)")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution for this:

```
\( ?ccc ?, ?yyy ?\)
```

Comment: Actually, there could be intervening strings between the ccc and the yyy, so it wouldn't pick up say (ccc, ddd, yyy) which it needs to do.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?  I'm not the best with regex, but I think you need to negate both parentheses.  By the way "*" is zero or more, so here `[^\(^\)]*` means zero or more occurrences of a character that's not a left or right parentheses:

```
\(.*ccc[^\(^\)]*yyy.*\)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your proposed regex `\(.*ccc[^\(\)]*yyy*\)`, the first instance of `.*` is going to consume more than you want it to because [VBA regexes are greedy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235254.aspx) - which is normal for regexes with the `*+?` quantifiers.

If you want to match "a left parenthesis and a right parenthesis that contain my search string 'foo' and my search string 'bar', but do not contain a sub-expression," one way to get that would be the following:

```
\([^\)]*foo[^\)]*bar[^\)]*\)
```

This regex will cover most cases where foo and bar are in the same set of parentheses. However, this will not match the text

```
(foo, (baz, qux), bar)
```

even though you imply that it should. Do you need it to match that case?

You also may want to look at the MSDN reference page for information about lazy `*+?` quantifiers, and if you want to construct a really robust regex for this, you're going to need to get into [backreferences and look-behind assertions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy).